# Apache Two way SSL certification for private server?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I want to use SSL to restrict access instead of having to have the user login.

Am I a correct in saying that if I setup a self authority and give the server and client certificates from the authority, then require the server to verify the client, this will prevent any client from accessing except ones that actually have the client certificate installed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is a reasonable description of how SSL client certificates work.